# Drupal 8.7.8 Custome Module Created Rest Resource (API) not found

Tags: php, drupal

**Directory structure:**

> module_name -> config -> install -> rest.resource.location_api.yml

```
id: location_api
plugin_id: location_api
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
    - POST 
    - PATCH
    - DELETE
  formats:
    - json
  authentication:
    - cookie
```

module_name/src/plugin/rest/resource/LocationApi.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\locations\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
//use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
//use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

//use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


/**
 * Provides a KDR's Rest Custom Resource For Locations
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "location_api",
 *   label = @Translation("KDR's Rest Custom Resource For Location"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/kdr-apis/v1.0/location/{sl_id}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/kdr-apis/v1.0/location"
 *   }
 * )
 */ 

class LocationApi extends ResourceBase {



}
```

but when I install the module, then it returns an error,

**Message**

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "entity_bundle:node" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionManager are: node_type, request_path, current_theme, user_role in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of /home/linuxdem/kdr.linuxdemos.me/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the Drupal 8 cache issue, I have resolved by clearing cache and re-installing module.